# How can I run a hardware test in lion?

Tags: macos, apple-hardware-test

My Mac was shipped with Lion. Therefore I have no install CDs that I could use to run a hardware test.

How can I run a hardware test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mac shipped with Lion, you should be able to run the hardware test by simply holding <kbd>D</kbd> when your computer boots.

If your mac did not ship with lion, you will need the original install disks to boot into the hardware test mode.

---

[Reference](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2011080811033562)